# Appending to a List

Tags: python

I'm having some trouble with my calculate_grade function. I'm trying to append the total to the end of each list(look at my desired output for example) I'm trying to accomplish this using a for loop

```
for x in score_list:
    i.append(x)
```

but i'm not getting my desired output. How would I set this up so that it doesn't keep the last total from the previous list.

```
def get_data(file_object):
    while True:
        try:
            file_object=input("Enter the name of the input file: ")
            input_file=open(file_object, "r")
            break
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("Error: file not found\n:")
    student_db=[]
    for line in input_file:
        fields=(line.split())
        name=int(fields[0])
        exam1=int(fields[1])
        exam2=int(fields[2])
        exam3=int(fields[3])
        in_class=int(fields[4])
        projects=int(fields[5])
        exercises=int(fields[6])
        record=[name,exam1,exam2,exam3,in_class,projects,exercises]
        student_db.append(record)
    student_db.sort()
    return student_db



def calculate_grade(all_students):
    #empty lists
    all_scores=[]
    score_list=[]
    #takes just scores from student_db and makes a list
    for scores in all_students:
        points=(scores[1:])
        all_scores.append(points)
    print("")
    print("")
    #makes seperate lists for each student 
    for i in all_scores:

        total_grade=0
        print(i)

        #totals up all of the scores for each student
        for j in i:
            total_grade+=j
            print(total_grade)
        #creates a list of the totals for each student
        score_list.append(total_grade)  
        #appends totals to each list of students
        for x in score_list:
            i.append(x)

    print("")
    print("")
    print("all_scores:",all_scores)
    print("")
    print("totals",score_list)



def main():
    all_students=get_data("data.tiny.txt")
    print(all_students)
    b=calculate_grade(all_students)
    print(b)
```

Input file "data.tiny.txt"

```
 001      115   135   150    50   437    15
  002     120    125   172    50   378    15
   003    120     123   125    50   354    14
    004   122      139   171    48   439    15
     005   95        88   100    46   194    14
```

Output:

```
Enter the name of the input file: data.tiny.txt
[[1, 115, 135, 150, 50, 437, 15], [2, 120, 125, 172, 50, 378, 15], [3, 120, 123, 125, 50, 354, 14], [4, 122, 139, 171, 48, 439, 15], [5, 95, 88, 100, 46, 194, 14]]


[115, 135, 150, 50, 437, 15]
115
250
400
450
887
902
[120, 125, 172, 50, 378, 15]
120
245
417
467
845
860
[120, 123, 125, 50, 354, 14]
120
243
368
418
772
786
[122, 139, 171, 48, 439, 15]
122
261
432
480
919
934
[95, 88, 100, 46, 194, 14]
95
183
283
329
523
537


all_scores: [[115, 135, 150, 50, 437, 15, 902], [120, 125, 172, 50, 378, 15, 902, 860], [120, 123, 125, 50, 354, 14, 902, 860, 786], [122, 139, 171, 48, 439, 15, 902, 860, 786, 934], [95, 88, 100, 46, 194, 14, 902, 860, 786, 934, 537]]

totals [902, 860, 786, 934, 537]
```

What needs to be fixed:

```
all_scores: [[115, 135, 150, 50, 437, 15, 902], [120, 125, 172, 50, 378, 15, 902, 860], [120, 123, 125, 50, 354, 14, 902, 860, 786], [122, 139, 171, 48, 439, 15, 902, 860, 786, 934], [95, 88, 100, 46, 194, 14, 902, 860, 786, 934, 537]]
```

Desired output for all_scores:

```
[[115, 135, 150, 50, 437, 15, 902], [120, 125, 172, 50, 378, 15, 860], [120, 123, 125, 50, 354, 14, 786], [122, 139, 171, 48, 439, 15, 934], [95, 88, 100, 46, 194, 14, 537]]
```

Comment: "What needs to be fixed" and "Desired output" looks the same. Where is the problem exactly? But I think you just want this: `i.append(sum(x))` instead of `i.append(x)`.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't notice the rest of the code. Now I am totally confused what do you want to achieve :)

Comment: so for example the first list is [115, 135, 150, 50, 437, 15, 902] the second one i get [120, 125, 172, 50, 378, 15, 902, 860]. I don't want to keep the 920  from the previous list. t's appending the 920 and so forth to every list. I just want the 860 and so forth. If you just compare my what needs to be fixed and my desired output maybe that will make it more simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are always appending your whole `score_list` to the list by:

```
#creates a list of the totals for each student
score_list.append(total_grade) 
#appends totals to each list of student
for x in score_list
    i.append(x)
```

If you don't want to do this, just don't do it. Instead only add the value you want to add:

```
i.append(total_grade)
```

Comment: I've tried that. The output I get is all_scores: [[115, 135, 150, 50, 437, 15, 902], [120, 125, 172, 50, 378, 15, 860, 860], [120, 123, 125, 50, 354, 14, 786, 786, 786], [122, 139, 171, 48, 439, 15, 934, 934, 934, 934], [95, 88, 100, 46, 194, 14, 537, 537, 537, 537, 537]]

Comment: Don't put that statement in a separate for loop.